# 投稿には平易な表現を心がけて欲しい

Tags: 討議

最近、いくつかの投稿で以下のようなフレーズをよく見かけます。

- Web APIやプログラムを**叩く**
- エラーメッセージやログファイルを**吐く**

「スラング」というと大げさかもしれませんが、これらはどちらかというと "話し言葉" に近く、文章の中で使うのは適さない気がします (特に第三者に読ませる前提の文章では)。

始めて見た場合でも前後の文脈で大抵は意味を理解することはできるでしょうが、これらの表現を使ってしまうと(その単語で検索しない限り)検索でも引っかからなくなり、情報の価値が下がってしまいます。

上記を踏まえて、以下のような対応を提案しますが如何でしょうか。

---

あなたが質問や回答を投稿する時：

- なるべく分かりやすい表現を心がけてください。省略語もなるべく避けるべきです。

あなたがこれらの表現を見かけた場合：

- より分かりやすい表現に編集で見直してみてください。
  ただしこの編集だけのために目を光らせる必要は無く、例えば誤字の修正のついで等で構わないと思います。

その他にも使いがち/使われがちな表現はありますか？何かご意見等あればぜひコメントや回答で教えてください。

参考： 英語版 Meta での略語に関する QA

- [Using abbreviations like “msg”, “req”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341274)
- [Is chat abbreviation allowed in answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345651)

Comment: タイトルの「平易な言葉」というのとはちょっと軸が違う提案かも、と思いました。複雑な熟語の使用を禁止したいというわけではなく、俗語を控えて欲しいという話に見えます。

Comment: 投稿するときの対応というのは、何かしらメッセージを出したいということでしょうか？　また日本語で省略語と言ってしまうと「API」みたいなのも当たってしまうのが気になります。

Comment: 提案内容とヘルプセンターに書かれている内容の異なる点は何ですか？同様の内容が既に [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 、 [良い回答を書くには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) 、 [自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) に書かれていると思います。

Answer (score 4):

提案の趣旨には賛同しますが、参加者間の合意が得られるようなルール化までは難しいのではと思います。

質問者／回答者自身や狭い範囲でしか通用しない「オレオレ用語」を使うべきではないとは思いますが、どこまでが「省略語や俗称」でどこからが「専門用語や慣用句」かという線引きは、技術分野や業界ごとの前提知識・常識、個人や所属組織の慣習・嗜好に依存してしまうと思います。

> あなたが質問や回答を投稿する時：
>
> - なるべく分かりやすい表現を心がけてください。省略語もなるべく避けるべきです。
>
> あなたがこれらの表現を見かけた場合：
>
> - より分かりやすい表現に編集で見直してみてください。
>     ただしこの編集だけのために目を光らせる必要は無く、例えば誤字の修正のついで等で構わないと思います。

質問者／回答者自身のスタンスとしては異議ありませんが、第三者による表現編集にはコミュニケーション上のトラブルリスクがあると思います。

慣用的に用いられる省略語は、（専門外であればなおさら）第三者からは謎めいて見えるものです。また適切に省略語を用いることで、共有済みのコンテキストを逐一説明する必要がなくなり、文章表現が簡潔になり課題にフォーカスしやすくなるメリットもあります。

---

> その他にも使いがち/使われがちな表現はありますか？

例えば「[不思議の国のSE用語 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/t_nakayama0714/items/478a8ed3a9ae143ad854)」などで沢山挙がっています（かなりフランク・非公式な用法が多いと思います）